# number changed after push back in vector

Tags: c++, function, recursion, vector

Here is my code (don't mind the french part, the essential is the code itself) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double SommeRecursive(vector <double> tableau) {
    int i = tableau.size();
    if (i > 1) {
        vector <double> clone = tableau;
        int dernier = clone[i-1];
        clone.pop_back();
        return dernier + SommeRecursive(clone);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector <double> tableau;
    double nombre;

    cout << "Nombre 1 : ";
    cin >> nombre;

    tableau.push_back(nombre);

    cout << "Nombre 2 : ";
    cin >> nombre;

    tableau.push_back(nombre);

    cout << "Nombre 3 : ";
    cin >> nombre;

    tableau.push_back(nombre);

    cout << "Résultat : " << SommeRecursive(tableau) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was testing out my code after using

```
gcc -std=c++14 -o main main.cpp && ./main
```

And if I enter number like 3.33, 3.33 and 3.33, I get the result 9.33 instead of 9.99. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your programs suffers from couple of problems:

1. You are truncating a `double` an `int` in line:

   ```
   int dernier = clone[i-1];
   ```
2. The function `SommeRecursive` does not have a `return` statement when the input is an empty vector. Hence, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Change it to:

```
double SommeRecursive(vector <double> tableau) {

   int i = tableau.size();

   if (i > 0) {
      vector <double> clone = tableau;
      double back = clone.back();
      clone.pop_back();

      return back + SommeRecursive(clone);
   }

   return 0.0;
}
```

Further refinement of the function that avoids creating copies of the input vector:

```
double SommeRecursive(std::vector<double>::const_iterator begin,
                      std::vector<double>::const_iterator end)
{
   if ( begin == end )
   {
      return 0.0;
   }

   return *begin + SommeRecursive(begin+1, end);
}

double SommeRecursive(std::vector<double> const& tableau)
{
   return SommeRecursive(tableau.begin(), tableau.end());
}
```

Comment: For once i beat you to it! But nice +1. Also if you do `i > 1` and `else return tableau` you save one function call.

Comment: @Ben, I didn't know we were in competition :) :)

Comment: Mostly me. I feel i am always second to post. Just a big kid, really.

Comment: Thanks a lot, although my mistake was really ... well I will not call me name lol but thanks again for pointing out others mistakes. If I could, I would have added another +1

Comment: @Ben, we are always in competition with other SO answerers, aren't we?

Comment: Hahaha, i guess so. Looks like you win this round.

Comment: @Ben, lucky break for me. May you win the next round :)

Answer (score 4):

This line is your issue:

```
int dernier = clone[i-1];
```

You are casting to an int. So when your recursive function calculates it will do this:

```
(int) 3.33 + (int) 3.33 + 3.33 = 3 + 3 + 3.33 = 9.33
```

Also i suspect your recursive function should be:

```
if (i > 1) {
   ...
   double dernier = clone[i-1];
   ...
} else {
   return tableau[0]; // This is your base condition.
}
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/TCT9GF)

Comment: Yes, I should have added an else for that part. But the solution return 0.0 was also good and fast.

Comment: @Gradiuss, actually the return 0.0 method is slower. It requires an extra call to `SommeRecursive` which means a context switch and potentially cache misses etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your sommeRecursive method you get the i-1th value in a int variable instead of double so it gets rounded down (ie. 3 + 3 + 3.33)

Comment: wow I feel dumb... thanks buddy. Should I delete that ask ? As it is not really interesting for others...

Comment: @Gradiuss This is not your only issue, read the other answers. Also dont delete the question. If people think its not worth keeping around it will be closed. But atm it is a good on topic question.

Comment: Okay i'll let it that way.